# Finding which API calls which API in microservice projects written in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-gateway

In order to determine the exceptions in the APIs;
I have microservice projects written in Spring and I want to find out which API calls which API. What methods do you use for this?

Comment: Try to implement logging with AOP on the controller layer which having tracing functionality.